# Trouble duel booting windows 11 and ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows

I’ve been following https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/ to troubleshoot my attempt at a win 11 and Ubuntu duel boot. After changing my configuration to AHCI I am getting the bsod. I attempted to follow along with the command prompt to troubleshoot and it will not recognise any of the bcdedit commands listed on the help page. My windows partition is set to C:

I’m new to using the terminal like this. Thankfully my data is backed up, but I’m kind of stuck.

Comment: My Dell only has NVMe drive, so used the Intel VMD driver with RAID on. Essentially same driver in Windows & Ubuntu.  If you change to AHCI, you must install the AHCI driver in Windows for it to work. You have to boot in recovery mode, install driver & may have to reboot several time for Windows to work.

Comment: I got frustrated and decided to load Ubuntu on its own without windows. I just started to learn how to code so I could use the problem solving skills I’m sure to gain.  Regardless thanks for the reply!